# Using circular crop instead of the default rectangle crop after picking image from gallery in android

Tags: android, image

I used [this](https://github.com/lvillani/android-cropimage) project to create an app that prompt user to pick an image from gallery and let the user to freely crop that selected image.

The default crop is rectangle, but what i want is circular crop. After did a lot of googling, i finally found this :

```
 intent.putExtra("circleCrop", true);
```

Sounds promising, unfortunately it has no effect. The crop is still rectangle.

This is my complete code :

```
        intent.setData(mImageCaptureUri);
        
        intent.putExtra("outputX", 200);
        intent.putExtra("outputY", 200);
        intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
        intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
        intent.putExtra("scale", true);
        intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        intent.putExtra("circleCrop", true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since different manufacturers implement their own interfaces for camera, the first method below will not work in all cases. For example, it worked on my Nexus S running stock 2.3.6 and not on my Galaxy Nexus on stock 4.3. Anyway, if you want to be able to crop your image in a circular fashion from the default crop action call it in the following way:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setData(imageUri); // Uri to the image you want to crop
intent.putExtra("outputX", Constants.PROFILE_PICTURE_SIZE);
intent.putExtra("outputY", Constants.PROFILE_PICTURE_SIZE);
intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
intent.putExtra("scale", true);
intent.putExtra("circleCrop", new String(""));
intent.putExtra("return-data", false);
File cropImageFile = new File(CROP_IMAGE_PATH); // Path to save the cropped image
intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(cropImageFile));
startActivityForResult(intent, CROP); // CROP = Code to track the result in  onActivityResult
```

This should start the default crop app that will look like this:
[image: Circular cropping]

If you've read this post by [commonsware](http://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html), you know that this will not always work. I suggest including one of the libraries from his post. The first one from [lvillani](https://github.com/lvillani/android-cropimage) is the CropImage activity extracted AOSP. Include the library and make call it with an intent similar to the one above. Make sure you include the circleCrop param in the intent.

ans from https://stackoverflow.com/posts/19640905/edit

Comment: Thanks. Yes, i used Ivillani's code, but how to export the AOSP? I dont really understand what to import so my code can run on all android devices

Comment: Btw, i tried your solution but the crop is still rectangle. Thanks